# Choose resistor for USB cable to mimic 1.5A load

Tags: resistors, usb, usb-device

I have a USB A 3.0 cable going from a PC to a USB testing device. In the future, a load will be between the pc and tester that will draw 1.5 amps. For now, I need to mimic that draw so that I can ensure the tester will work adequately while loaded.

My thought was to use a 3.3ohm resistor, since the USB supply voltage is 5V.

Is this correct, or is it more complicated than that?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it is not correct.

You can't draw that amount of current from an USB port without negotiating how much current you will draw. The original device asks for a certain amount of current, which the host/PC may currently being capable of providing. But the current you draw with a resistor is not negotiated so you will be drawing more current which the host/PC won't know and might not be able to provide.

Also the assumption of 5V and 3.33 ohm resistor only applies for 5V voltage. If the devices negotiate a higher voltage then something may damage as you can't have a 3.33 ohm resistor on 20V supply without damaging something.

Also, USB Type A ports are not rated for more than 1.5A of current, so trying to draw more can cause voltage drop or port to shut down.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a simple way to negotiate the 1.5A additional current draw for this?

Comment: Realistically, USB ports almost never limit the current, and almost never require the negotiation. If this is a DIY project and not something you're selling, you can almost certainly just draw the current you want, without any negotiation. (Ping: @Winters637)

Comment: @td127 that is incorrect. This is not Type C and Type C supplies are not required to give 3A as some only support 1.5A. And type A has official limit of 1.5A so it is not a good idea to draw whatever negotiated plus 1.5A without negotiating.

Comment: @Justme I did observe that the normal 5V reading on my dmm drops to about 3.1V when I add the 3.3 ohm resistor on there. So is it not possible to draw what I need using usb-a? If not, do you think usb-c could since it has the higher rating? Also, the resistor is rated for 10w so that shouldn't be limiting power itself. Also, my question about using usb-c does assume it can handle 3A from the port, not 1.5A

Comment: @td127 USB-C hosts are not required to supply 3A. They must support minimum of 1.5A but are allowed to support 3A, or more via PD.

Comment: @td127 It reads in the USB standard. The device must monitor for the CC wire how much current is available, and never draw more than advertized to be available. Options are 3A, 1.5A, and for Type A to Type C adapters 900mA.

Comment: Retracted my comments about USB-C guaranteeing 5V @3A. That’s true for Thunderbolt3 connections using USB-C connectors but not for standard USB.